# Gazebo magnet simulation

Tags: gazebo, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to make two objects exert forces on each other in gazebo, to simulate for instance a magnet or vacuum gripper?

If not, is it possible to dynamically connect and disconnect object frames?

Kind regards,
Eli

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11606/gazebo-magnet-simulation/) by [erkmns](https://answers.ros.org/users/1230/erkmns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-10-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-11-04**:
Can you put your result in some website or video ? Should be very interesting.

**Comment by [erkmns](https://answers.ros.org/users/1230/erkmns/) on 2011-10-27**:
We came up with a work-around, making external forces interact with both objects, using the apply_body_wrench service.
The reference frame being the frame of the other object, and the wrench defined as a negative force in direction z.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-20**:
Good question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually, it is much better to use Gazebo plugins instead of the `apply_body_wrench` service. The reason is that a Gazebo plugin is run exactly once for every simulation cycle, while the `apply_body_wrench` service interacts with the simulation in irregular intervals, leading to instabilities.

To do this:

- specify each cubelet in an URDF file
- add a Gazebo controller which excerts the magnetic forces

As an example of how to do this, you can look at the package `manipulation_worlds`, where they use a Plugin called `gazebo_ros_grasp_hack` to magically attach a grasped object to the PR2 gripper when both fingers make contact, in order to stop it from jittering out.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/27483/abdullah/) on 2016-08-28**:
Hi there, I saw your answer was written in 2012, I hope you are still there following gazebo, I have been trying to use this gazebo_ros_grasp_hack for so long and I couldnt figure out how to use it, may be because there isnt much of tutorials around for this plugin. I would be really really grateful